# PIC32mx Timer5 not working

Tags: pic, timer, interrupts, microchip

I am struggling to put my Timer5 working properly. I think I have enabled all the registers but the interrupt never occurs. I already put a break point inside in the `FingerprintRun()` in the `asm("nop")` sentence and I found the `TMR5` never goes above `0x0000`.

```
void __ISR(_TIMER_5_VECTOR,IPL4) _T5Interrupt(void)
{
    T5CONbits.ON = 0;
    TMR5 = 0;
    IFS0bits.T5IF = 0;
    UART_TX = 0;
    char x = 'b';
    UARTFingerprintWriteChar( x );
}

void initTIMER5( void ){  
    __asm__("EI");
    INTConfigureSystem(INT_SYSTEM_CONFIG_MULT_VECTOR); //configure multi vector
    INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt(); //enable interrupts

    T5CONbits.TON = 0;

    T5CONbits.TGATE = 0;
    T5CONbits.SIDL = 0;
    T5CONbits.TCKPS = 0;// 0b111;1:256 prescale value
    TMR5 = 0;
    PR5=0xD0;
    IFS0bits.T5IF = 0; // Clear timer interrupt flag
    IPC5bits.T5IP = 4; // Setting Timer 5 priority to level 4 of 7
    IPC5bits.T5IS = 1; // setting timer 5 sub priority to level 1 of 3

    IEC0bits.T5IE = 1; // Enable timer interrupts
    T5CONbits.TON = 1;
}

void main() {
    initTIMER5();
    asm("nop");
    while(1);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I upvoted, cheer up! But you need to be more specific, for example I can't see where do you set the counter or increment TMR5. Where do you call FingerprintRun, what is the class Task and more importantly where is your main function?

Comment: Ok, I will update the code for better understading. Thanks for the tip. @Alperözel the timer should increment by himself, no? I just set TMR5 = 0;

Comment: Insert a while(1); after the asm("nop"); inside the main. The code may be crashing because getting to the end of main is bad.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing that already. Probably it was a copy-paste problem.

Comment: What is the exact model of you processor?

Comment: PIC32MX575f512h

Comment: Are you sure that the clock is running? Could you also post your configuration word?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34648/discussion-between-scuba-and-vini-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the interrupt is not being enabled (don't know why) so I found another way to make it work.

Instead of: IEC0bits.T5IE = 1; // Enable timer interrupts

I am using: IEC0 = 0x100000;

Comment: You might submit this to technical support. Also you may want to use IEC0SET so you dont clear the other bits...